# I keep getting 400 error(travelerId not existing) on calling the CreateOrder API

Tags: amadeus

I am on a **test Account**.

On printing the travelerPricings Object to console, I have this

```
[
  {
    travelerId: '1',
    fareOption: 'STANDARD',
    travelerType: 'ADULT',
    price: {
      currency: '',
      total: '',
      base: '',
      taxes: [Array],
      refundableTaxes: ''
    },
    fareDetailsBySegment: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    travelerId: '2',
    fareOption: 'STANDARD',
    travelerType: 'CHILD',
    price: {
      currency: '',
      total: '',
      base: '',
      taxes: [Array],
      refundableTaxes: ''
    },
    fareDetailsBySegment: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Yet on the Api Response, I keep getting the error pointer as

```
/data/flightOffers[0]/travelerPricings[1]"
```

Which is not true. As seen in the log shared above,

`travelerPricings[1].travelerId = '2'`

Please Why could this error come up? Thanks

**Based on the Request, Here is the sample payload**

```
{"data":
{
   "flightOffers": [
      {
          "type": "flight-offer",
          "id": "1",
          "source": "GDS",
          "instantTicketingRequired": false,
          "nonHomogeneous": false,
          "paymentCardRequired": false,
          "lastTicketingDate": "2022-08-01",
          "itineraries": [
              {
                  "segments": [
                      {
                          "departure": {
                              "iataCode": "SYD",
                              "terminal": "1",
                              "at": "2022-08-01T11:35:00"
                          },
                          "arrival": {
                              "iataCode": "MNL",
                              "terminal": "2",
                              "at": "2022-08-01T16:50:00"
                          },
                          "carrierCode": "PR",
                          "number": "212",
                          "aircraft": {
                              "code": "333"
                          },
                          "operating": {
                              "carrierCode": "PR"
                          },
                          "duration": "PT7H15M",
                          "id": "15",
                          "numberOfStops": 0,
                          "co2Emissions": [
                              {
                                  "weight": 716,
                                  "weightUnit": "KG",
                                  "cabin": "BUSINESS"
                              }
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "departure": {
                              "iataCode": "MNL",
                              "terminal": "1",
                              "at": "2022-08-01T19:20:00"
                          },
                          "arrival": {
                              "iataCode": "BKK",
                              "at": "2022-08-01T21:50:00"
                          },
                          "carrierCode": "PR",
                          "number": "732",
                          "aircraft": {
                              "code": "320"
                          },
                          "operating": {
                              "carrierCode": "PR"
                          },
                          "duration": "PT3H30M",
                          "id": "16",
                          "numberOfStops": 0,
                          "co2Emissions": [
                              {
                                  "weight": 148,
                                  "weightUnit": "KG",
                                  "cabin": "BUSINESS"
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "segments": [
                      {
                          "departure": {
                              "iataCode": "BKK",
                              "at": "2022-08-05T22:50:00"
                          },
                          "arrival": {
                              "iataCode": "MNL",
                              "terminal": "2",
                              "at": "2022-08-06T03:15:00"
                          },
                          "carrierCode": "PR",
                          "number": "733",
                          "aircraft": {
                              "code": "321"
                          },
                          "operating": {
                              "carrierCode": "PR"
                          },
                          "duration": "PT3H25M",
                          "id": "59",
                          "numberOfStops": 0,
                          "co2Emissions": [
                              {
                                  "weight": 148,
                                  "weightUnit": "KG",
                                  "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                              }
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "departure": {
                              "iataCode": "MNL",
                              "terminal": "1",
                              "at": "2022-08-06T22:10:00"
                          },
                          "arrival": {
                              "iataCode": "SYD",
                              "terminal": "1",
                              "at": "2022-08-07T09:45:00"
                          },
                          "carrierCode": "PR",
                          "number": "211",
                          "aircraft": {
                              "code": "333"
                          },
                          "operating": {
                              "carrierCode": "PR"
                          },
                          "duration": "PT9H35M",
                          "id": "60",
                          "numberOfStops": 0,
                          "co2Emissions": [
                              {
                                  "weight": 358,
                                  "weightUnit": "KG",
                                  "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ],
          "price": {
              "currency": "NGN",
              "total": "1479460.00",
              "base": "1298255.00",
              "fees": [
                  {
                      "amount": "0.00",
                      "type": "SUPPLIER"
                  },
                  {
                      "amount": "0.00",
                      "type": "TICKETING"
                  },
                  {
                      "amount": "0.00",
                      "type": "FORM_OF_PAYMENT"
                  }
              ],
              "grandTotal": "1479460.00",
              "billingCurrency": "NGN"
          },
          "pricingOptions": {
              "fareType": [
                  "PUBLISHED"
              ],
              "includedCheckedBagsOnly": false
          },
          "validatingAirlineCodes": [
              "PR"
          ],
          "travelerPricings": [
              {
                  "travelerId": "1",
                  "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                  "travelerType": "ADULT",
                  "price": {
                      "currency": "NGN",
                      "total": "840536",
                      "base": "740769",
                      "taxes": [
                          {
                              "amount": "384.00",
                              "code": "G8"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "19112.00",
                              "code": "WY"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "896.00",
                              "code": "E7"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "18329.00",
                              "code": "AU"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "42766.00",
                              "code": "YQ"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "9320.00",
                              "code": "LI"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "8960.00",
                              "code": "TS"
                          }
                      ],
                      "refundableTaxes": "108123"
                  },
                  "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                      {
                          "segmentId": "15",
                          "cabin": "BUSINESS",
                          "fareBasis": "DBAU",
                          "class": "D",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 40,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "segmentId": "16",
                          "cabin": "BUSINESS",
                          "fareBasis": "DBAU",
                          "class": "D",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 40,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "segmentId": "59",
                          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                          "fareBasis": "KBAU",
                          "class": "K",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 30,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "segmentId": "60",
                          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                          "fareBasis": "KBAU",
                          "class": "K",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 30,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "travelerId": "2",
                  "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                  "travelerType": "CHILD",
                  "price": {
                      "currency": "NGN",
                      "total": "638924",
                      "base": "557486",
                      "taxes": [
                          {
                              "amount": "384.00",
                              "code": "G8"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "19112.00",
                              "code": "WY"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "896.00",
                              "code": "E7"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "42766.00",
                              "code": "YQ"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "9320.00",
                              "code": "LI"
                          },
                          {
                              "amount": "8960.00",
                              "code": "TS"
                          }
                      ],
                      "refundableTaxes": "89794"
                  },
                  "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                      {
                          "segmentId": "15",
                          "cabin": "BUSINESS",
                          "fareBasis": "DBAU",
                          "class": "D",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 40,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "segmentId": "16",
                          "cabin": "BUSINESS",
                          "fareBasis": "DBAU",
                          "class": "D",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 40,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "segmentId": "59",
                          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                          "fareBasis": "KBAU",
                          "class": "K",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 30,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "segmentId": "60",
                          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                          "fareBasis": "KBAU",
                          "class": "K",
                          "includedCheckedBags": {
                              "weight": 30,
                              "weightUnit": "KG"
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ],
"travelers": [ {
    "id":          "1",
    "dateOfBirth": "1982-01-16",
    "name":        {
      "firstName": "JORGE",
      "lastName":  "GONZALES"
    },
    "gender":  "MALE",
    "contact": {
      "emailAddress": "jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es",
      "phones":       [ {
        "deviceType":         "MOBILE",
        "countryCallingCode": "34",
        "number":             "480080076"
      } ]
    },
    "documents": [ {
      "documentType":     "PASSPORT",
      "birthPlace":       "Madrid",
      "issuanceLocation": "Madrid",
      "issuanceDate":     "2015-04-14",
      "number":           "00000000",
      "expiryDate":       "2025-04-14",
      "issuanceCountry":  "ES",
      "validityCountry":  "ES",
      "nationality":      "ES",
      "holder":           true
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

**MY Request using the NodeSDK**

```
const {data:{flightOffers}} = req.body;

const {result} = await Amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(
        JSON.stringify({
          'data': {
            'type':         'flight-order',
            'flightOffers': [ flightOffers[ 0 ] ],
            'travelers':    travelers
          }
        })
      );
```

This is *quite lengthy*, but I did this so it is easy to just re-create the exact Scenario in case the issue is somewhere in the payload I am sending.

Comment: Can you share an Snipped code with your call, in order to review internally and offer a better support?

Comment: I have added some more details to the post. Please Check it out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you request Flight Create Order API, you have only put 1 traveler's information at the end that's why the error comes. you are requesting for flight order for 2 persons (1 adult and 1 child) so both information should be attached at the end.

below is a node example for the entire flow from Flight offer search, pricing, and create order. you may get a different error if some segments are not available, but the issue that you faced regarding travelers is resolved.

```
amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get({
originLocationCode: 'SYD',
destinationLocationCode: 'BKK',
departureDate: '2022-08-01',
adults: '1',
children: '1'
}).then(function (flightOffersResponse) {
  return amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.pricing.post(
    JSON.stringify({
      'data': {
        'type': 'flight-offers-pricing',
        'flightOffers': [flightOffersResponse.data[0]]
      }
    })
  )
}).then(function (pricingResponse) {
    return amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(
      JSON.stringify({
      'data': {
      'type': 'flight-order',
      'flightOffers': [pricingResponse.data.flightOffers[0]],
      'travelers': [{
        "id": "1",
        "dateOfBirth": "1982-01-16",
        "name": {
          "firstName": "JORGE",
          "lastName": "GONZALES"
        },
        "gender": "MALE",
        "contact": {
          "emailAddress": "jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es",
          "phones": [{
            "deviceType": "MOBILE",
            "countryCallingCode": "34",
            "number": "480080076"
          }]
        },
        "documents": [{
          "documentType": "PASSPORT",
          "birthPlace": "Madrid",
          "issuanceLocation": "Madrid",
          "issuanceDate": "2015-04-14",
          "number": "00000000",
          "expiryDate": "2025-04-14",
          "issuanceCountry": "ES",
          "validityCountry": "ES",
          "nationality": "ES",
          "holder": true
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "dateOfBirth": "2012-10-11",
        "gender": "FEMALE",
        "contact": {
          "emailAddress": "jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es",
          "phones": [
            {
              "deviceType": "MOBILE",
              "countryCallingCode": "34",
              "number": "480080076"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "firstName": "ADRIANA",
          "lastName": "GONZALES"
        }
      }]
    }
  })
);
}).then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
}).catch(function (response) {
console.error(response);
 });
```